# How do I convert an ascii code to the escaped 'screen friendly' view?

Tags: c#, .net, ascii

In C# .Net I'm looking to convert an ascii value (13, 16 etc) to its escaped view (eg \n, \r, \t etc) for a selector. Is there a built in way to do this or do I have to resort to using a look up table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of... but it would be a very small lookup table anyway. It may be easiest to use a switch statement, in fact:

```
public static string Escape(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '\n': return "\\n";
        case '\r': return "\\r";
        case '\t': return "\\t";
        case '\b': return "\\b";
        // etc
        default: return c.ToString(); // Perhaps...
    }
}
```

You could potentially also return `\uxxxx` for any nonprintable characters.

Comment: Those aren't verbatim strings so you'd just be passing out the unprintable character again, should either be `@"\n"` or `"\\n"`

Comment: Oops - I suspect this was written in great haste, and that I was about to fix it up but got distracted. Thanks Luke!