# What language are \r\n ? - I need to convert the space to its &nbsp; eqivalent

Tags: php, html, string

I need to convert all the new line, carriage returns, and spaces into HTML markup. I am using string replace to replace `\n` with `<br />` and need to find a way to convert the spaces at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an ascii code to the escaped 'screen friendly' view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508523/how-do-i-convert-an-ascii-code-to-the-escaped-screen-friendly-view)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Is it ascii? I looked up ascii before I posted my question and was still unable to find \n or anything for a space character

Comment: @developerwjk I have the nl sorted.. I need to convert the space equivalent to &nbsp;

Comment: Are you aiming to replace **arbitrary whitespace** with `&nbsp;` _after_ you have already replaced \r\n, or do you want to replace _all_ whitespace (including tabs, new lines, any number of subsequent spaces) with `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Also, converting just any `space` characters into `&nbsp;` is _not_ a trivial task for simple string replace or regex. You need to know if you are inside tag definitions or within `<pre>` tags.

Comment: It represents newline and carriage return character

Answer (score 0):

`nl2br()` would work for the newlines to `<br />` but to do it all you still use `str_replace()`:

```
$result = str_replace(array(" ","\n","\r"), array("&nbsp;","<br />",""), $string);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this convert `<a href="http://example.com">` to `<a&nbsp;href="http://example.com">`?

Comment: Yes, but OP didn't give any input and stated _convert all the new line, carriage returns, and spaces into HTML markup_

Comment: Yes, you are right. For some reason, I took HTML input for granted.